# Check for future date in PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I am trying to make user form where user need to enter a future date. So far what I did is

```
$now  = new DateTime();
$expDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $expDate);

if(empty($expDate)){
   $ErrE = "Enter EXP Date";
   $userinput = false;
}

if ($expDate >= $now)
{
     echo 'Enter Correct date';   
}else{
     echo "Ok";

}
```

HTML

```
<input type="date" class="form-control"  placeholder="EXP ON" name="expDate">
```

But in every scenario the output is showing Ok. Can somebody explain me what is wrong in code?

Thanks

Comment: When the input date is not correct [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) returns `FALSE` and `FALSE < $now`. If `$expDate` is not a date then you should not run the second `if`.

Comment: You can also use strtotime which converts the string date to UNIX time

Answer (score 0):

The following line produces the following error:

```
$expDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $expDate);
```

> Undefined variable: expDate

Which only makes sense since you never initialized the variable, yet you are trying to use it for its initialization.

Change that line to a future date ex.

```
$expDate = new DateTime('2018-01-01');
```

And your code example should work as intended.